# Inadequate Review Audit Test

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Going through the close votes review queueueueueueueueue I ran into this audit.

---

[image]

---

Given that I can already see the question had been closed it seems less than useful as an audit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a broken review audit. There's a [question on mSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185982/189912) about it already, though that question doesn't really address this specific aspect of the problem. (This question doesn't quite do it either, so I'm going to [post this separately on mSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186109/189912).) At the moment there's a lot of review audit breakage related to the change in close functionality.

The "right" answer is Leave Open.

Comment: Which is terrible because I would have closed that shit anyway. I just mark that up to the review audits having a surprisingly high failure rate.

Comment: Review audits being crap is a whole separate issue. This one's just plain buggy (and crap).

Comment: They got both kinds: buggy *and* crap.

Comment: DevOps - Set sail for fail!

Answer (score 1):

Should be working correctly now. See [this mSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188661) for details.

Comment: I may post a question later, but I'm in a rush.. I just got the same review audit twice, with only 5 or 6 real reviews in between.