# Another bad review audit: same audit question

Tags: bug, reviewing

While reviewing close votes, I got the same review audit twice in short succession:

[image]

Even if it wasn't pretty obviously an audit, it's certainly not effective to give me the same audit 8 reviews after I last saw it.

Comment: People have been complaining about the review audits since they were implemented. I haven't seen any changes, so I'd assume nobody is working on it right now, and there's a reasonable chance the whole system will be scrapped eventually.

Comment: @ChrisS: Someone is doing something http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5598/inadequate-review-audit-test

Comment: @Iain Missed that - thanks for pointing it out!